# SKLearn: Losing names of columns when using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a string representing an article, called `text`.  I'm trying to run TFIDF on it and get a dataframe as a result.  The resulting dataframe should have each word as a column name.  Here's my attempt:

```
corpus = [text]
tfidf_transformer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1,1), use_idf=True)
tfidf_df = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_df.toarray())

print 'tfidf_df: ', tfidf_df.head()
```

After this code runs, I have numbers as my column names instead of words representing the features from TFIDF.

How should I get the columns to be each word encountered in the `text` string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `vocabulary_` attribute from `TfidfVectorizer.`

**Example**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

corpus = ["quick brown fox", "something else"]

tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1,1), use_idf=True).fit(corpus)
vocab = tf_idf.vocabulary_
tf_idf_df = tf_idf.transform(corpus)

# make sure keys are sorted
tf_idf_df = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_df.toarray(), columns=sorted(vocab.keys()))
tf_idf_df
     brown      else      fox      quick something
0  0.57735  0.000000  0.57735    0.57735  0.000000
1  0.00000  0.707107  0.00000    0.00000  0.707107
```